# eclipse e4 PartStack change listener

Tags: eclipse, listener, e4

i need a listener for my partstack when someone clicks on another tab.

I have seen that PartStack should have an function addListener. But it seems this function is not avaliable anymore :(

https://www.cct.lsu.edu/~rguidry/ecl31docs/api/org/eclipse/ui/internal/PartStack.html

Also the idea to register an IPartListener on EPartService seems to be wrong here.

Comment: That reference is not the E4 PartStack so is irrelevant. The EPartService IPartListener should be OK for this.

Comment: Ok thank you greg but I do not find any example how to use the IPartListener. It will be added to the PartService - ok - but where is the reference to the actual PartStack I want to monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IPartListener` from `EPartService`.

The listener tells you about changes to the state of all parts, you can check if the part is in the part stack you are interested with something like:

```java
@Override
public void partActivated(final MPart part)
{
  Object parent = part.getParent();

  if (parent instanceof MPartStack)
   {
     MPartStack partStack = (MPartStack)parent;

     String stackId = partStack.getElementId();

     // TODO check the id is your stack
   }
```